# Run Python script daily in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to the world of GCP. I have a Python script that downloads data from an API (which requires credential files in JSON format), then cleans the data, and sends it to a table in BigQuery (or Redshift if necessary).

The script is quite simple and takes only a few seconds to run.

I have all the necessary files (credentials and script) in a GCP bucket. I managed to execute the code from CloudShell without any problem, but now I want to automate this code.

I was trying with Cloud Functions, but I can't understand how they work since you need to pass a "function" for it to execute (at least that's what I understood) and try execute zip file too but don't work, and I haven't been able to implement this Cloud function.

Basically, what I want is for this script to run every day at 4 AM.

The final use case is to execute about 50 similar scripts (multiple clients with the same source). I'm not sure if using Cloud Functions is the best approach, or if I should set up a virtual machine and execute the scripts using cron (since there are many scripts, I'm not sure if I can run all of them within a single virtual machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your script take a few seconds, I don't recommend to use a Compute Engine (a VM) because you won't use it most of the time (and you will pay for nothing).

The Cloud Functions and Cloud Run services answer to HTTP request. So, you can wrap your script in a "functions" invoked by a HTTP request, execute your script, and when it's done, send back an HTTP code (usually 200 when the script is OK).

With Cloud Functions you simply have to provide the function, with Cloud Run, you have to create the webserver and the endpoint(s) that answer HTTP request. With Cloud Run, you can serve multiple endpoint, with Cloud Functions only one. It's up to you to adapt/manage your code and deployment according to your several customers.

With Cloud Run, you have also to manage your container; It's easy to build but it's another thing to do and know.

If you don't want to wrap your script in a HTTP handler, you can use Cloud Run jobs. You still have to provide a container, but this time you simply put your script and that's all!! The entrypoint is the command that you run on your Cloud Shell.

---

Finally, with Cloud Run, Cloud Functions or Cloud Run Jobs, you have to invoke your execution everyday. For that you can use Cloud Scheduler which perform an HTTP call:

- either to your HTTP endpoint (For Cloud Functions or Cloud Run)
- or to the Cloud Run Jobs API (REST API call to execution endpoint to start your container and your script).

---

Last warning, because you are new on GCP and to take the good habits from the beginning: the service account key file (your JSON credential) are useless when you run your code on Google Cloud (and even on other cloud). They are useful in very rare case. The rest of the time it's more a security weakness and I strongly recommend not to use them, never as long as you can.

To replace them, you can use the [ADC: Application Default Credential](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc). In summary, the Google Cloud client library can detect automatically the runtime environment and use either your own user credential or the runtime environment service account credential.

Have a look to Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, Cloud Scheduler service account and security configuration.

Comment: If a use a container, credentials json are still necessary? 

How can manage the authenticantion topic when maybe just work in multiple proyects, with several clients?

Comment: The usage of JSON credential depends on the runtime environment, not the packaging mode (i.e. container or not). If you have multiple project, clients and so on, I strongly recommend to use service account impersonation. In summary, use your user account, to use a service account on its behalf (i.e. generate a token with the service account credential, and not with yours). The gcloud CLI and the client libraries support the impersonation mode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Finally today i could run the script use a Docker container and Cloud Run!